# C++ initialize an empty list in class

Tags: c++, class, initialization

How can I initialize an empty list as a private member in a C++ class? I don't want to prompt the user to pass in an empty list, but rather just create one when I make a new instance of the class.

header.h

```
class MyClass{
public:
    MyClass();
private:
    list<int> myList;
}
```

MyClass.cpp

```
MyClass::MyClass()
    :myList(list<int>){}
```

This doesn't work as written, what am I missing here?

Comment: Try dropping `(list<int>)`, the compiler don't need the type again.

Comment: You mean an empty vector?

Comment: @Jaochim Pileborg Thank you I believe that was the problem, I though I had to specify this in the constructor also.

Comment: Drop the constructor completely. The default initialization of a list is an empty list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to do anything. The default constructor, like the name suggests, is called by default. So this is already correct:

```
class MyClass{
public:
    MyClass() { }         // c++03
    MyClass() = default; // c++11
private:
    std::list<int> myList;
};
```

If you want to still have `myList` in the member initializer list, you can do that by simply providing empty parens:

```
class MyClass{
public:
    MyClass()
    : myList() // explicitly use default ctor
   {}
private:
    std::list<int> myList;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I was aware of the the default constructor but didn't realize that the declaration of the list as a private member was sufficient

Comment: @LBaelish It doesn't have to be private. Constructing a class must construct all of its members - if you don't specify a constructor for a member, the default is used.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to optionally hand in a user-defined value, you can use the initializer list of your constructor. Additionally, default the list to an empty content.

```
class MyClass{
public:
    MyClass(list<int> theList = {}) : myList(theList) {}

private:
    list<int> myList;
}
```

Comment: This incurs an unnecessary copy.

Comment: Sure, but you get the added benefit of empty initialize when the optional parameter is not set. And optional parameters are a totally common scenario :). Just adding this option for the sake of completeness.